# Extract all text from possibly nested <span>s on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage with a variety of text snippets enclosed in `<span class="x"></span>` tags. I'd like to generate an ordered list of each such snippet. Straightforward enough.

The wrinkle: It frequently occurs that there are additional `<span class="x">` tags nested inside the outer ones, which I don't care about. Essentially, I want a list of every string that is within at least one `<span class="x">` tag, but any additional nested such tags should be ignored and discarded.

Here is some example HTML:

```html
<p>
  Outer text. <span class="x">Inside a single span.</span> Back to outer text once more. <span class="x"><span class="x">Inside two spans</span> or just one</span>. Perhaps a <span class="x">single span contains <span class="x">several</span> 
  <span class="x">nests</span>  <span class="x">within <span class="x">it</span>
  </span>!</span>
</p>
<span class="x">Maybe there's a span out here.</span><span class="x">(Or two.)</span>
<p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="x">Or <span class="x">in</span><span class="x">here</span></span>.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
<p>
  <span>No.</span>  <span>Still no, but<span class="x">yes</span>.</span>
</p>
```

along with my desired output:

```
[ "Inside a single span.",
  "Inside two spans or just one",
  "single span contains several nests within it!",
  "Maybe there's a span out here.",
  "(Or two.)",
  "Or inhere",
  "yes" ]
```

Specific features of this example I'd like to call attention to:

- The outermost span can occur at any depth within the larger HTML document.
- The spans can be nested arbitrarily deep. <sup>(Though in practice I haven't found any instances with more than 3 or 4 layers so far)</sup>
- There may or may not be whitespace between neighboring outer spans; I'd like their contents parsed as separate strings either way.
- Span tags without class "x" are not desired.
- There may or may not be whitespace between neighboring inner tags; I'd like to preserve this as-is.
- I do not anticipate any `<span class="x">` tag containing any HTML tags *other than* additional nested `<span class="x">` tags.

I would be happy with a JavaScript + jQuery solution, or a Python3 + BeautifulSoup solution, or something else entirely if it is sufficiently better suited to the task at hand than either of those.

Comment: you want else `<span>Maybe there's a span out here.</span><span>(Or two.)</span>` even though theres no `x` class?

Comment: No, I don't. Good point, that's a detail I missed in the example.

Comment: If you try something I can help you, but I am not going to write the code for you. Unless you want to pay me :)

Comment: I'm not looking for a full solution, just maybe a suggested algorithm!

Comment: Ok... here is a suggestion: $('span').each(function(){someGlobalArray[] = $(this).text();}); Now you just need to solve the ignore children part

Comment: Is requirement to get text of only parent element `span` and first `span` descendant of parent element `span`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('span.x').each(function(index, el) {
console.log(el.childNodes[0].textContent)
});
```

or

```
$('span.x').each(function(index, el) {
 $(el).text();
});
```

this is ofcourse jquery example.
It will list in console all your spans text values.

Simply build with this snippet your ordered list.

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.childNodes')`

Comment: This hasnt the right output+crahses if the span has no content

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I've fixed examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a complete list of text in JavaScript via simple jQuery statement:

```
$("span.x").map(function(e) {return $(this).text() == "" ? null : $(this).text()})
```

It's up to you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

JS solution:

```
function detect(elem, rettext=false){
var answer=[];
//loop trough childs
for(i=0;i<elem.childNodes.length;i++){
  e=elem.childNodes[i];
  if(e.nodeType==3&&rettext){
      //elems child is direct x child+text so lets add it
      answer.push(e.textContent);
  }else{
  //elems child is an element so lets loop trough
  if( (" " + e.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(" x ") > -1 ){
       //e is x so lets get direct childs and create one string
 answer.push(detect(e,true).join(""));
     }else{
     //not x so lets loop trough and return array

     a=detect(e);
     for(b=0;b<a.length;b++){
     answer.push(a[b]);
     }
     }
     }
     }
     return answer;
  }



 //start if window loaded
  window.onload=()=>{
  theansweris=detect(document.body);
  }
```

This function loops trough all elements of the html tree. If one of the elements is an x class, all the inner results are joined, and the direct textNodes are added

Note:
This uses ES6. If you dont know what that is please write a comment, so i explain it to you

Answer (score 1):

Replacing inner span tags with blanks should do the job :

```
var st = [];
$("span.x").map(function(e) {
    st.push($(this).html().replace('<span class="x">','').replace('</span>',''));
});

console.log(st);
```

This is a bit dirty but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

first get the top most spans with class`x` but checking it doesnt have a parent with class `x`. then get the `innerText` of these.

```js
var topMost = $('span.x').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).parents('.x').length;
});

var texts = topMost.map(function() {
  return this.innerText;
});

console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Outer text. <span class="x">Inside a single span.</span> Back to outer text once more. <span class="x"><span class="x">Inside two spans</span> or just one</span>. Perhaps a <span class="x">single span contains <span class="x">several</span> 
  <span class="x">nests</span>  <span class="x">within <span class="x">it</span>
  </span>!</span>
</p>
<span>Maybe there's a span out here.</span><span>(Or two.)</span>
<p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="x">Or <span class="x">in</span><span class="x">here</span></span>.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
<p>
  <span>No.</span> <span>Still no, but<span class="x">yes</span>.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

not as elegant as the other solutions...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'x'})

children = []
for span in spans:
    chilren.extend(span.findChildren())

children = [child.text for child in children]

results = [span.text for span in spans if span.text not in children]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the plethora of responses here, I wrote a BeautifulSoup solution myself. It works by repeatedly finds the next `<span class="x">` in the html, then removing all tags from inside of it before finding the next one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

current_span = soup.head
while True:
    current_span = current_span.find_next("span", class_="x")
    if current_span:
        current_span.string = "".join(current_span.strings)
    else: break

return [span.string for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="x")]
```